# PHP encryption for the common man?

Tags: php, encryption

What would be a good pair of common-case functions to encrypt and decrypt data in PHP?

Assumptions:

- You have a string which acts as a key that will not change
- You have a string of sensitive data to be encrypted
- The encryption function should accept only the key and the plain data
- The decryption function should accept only the key and the encrypted data
- PHP 5.5 is available
- Only PHP modules you can safely assume to be installed can be used

For when someone says "I just want to encrypt some data" and you want to tell them to do their research and understand the consequences of such decisions before implementing something, but they have a deadline so you have to provide a snippet anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using successfully this two custom functions via web url like parameters for some sensitive info.. you can take alook and see if it fits your needs :)

This can easily be used in backend only or what ever you like,,

https://gist.github.com/mkdizajn/88a528f2a9ecee880c2e#file-php-encode_decode-helper-function-php

```
$key = 'your password for encryption';
function hideinfo( $key, $string ){ return rawurlencode( base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))))); }
function showinfo( $key, $string ){ return rawurldecode( rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode(rawurldecode($string)), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0")); }
```

I've been passing to this functions arrays with something like:

print_r( my_array(), true ) and used all sorts of char encodings and that works great also,,

hth, k

Comment: Thanks! I made a few adjustments and created https://gist.github.com/richjenks/1cfabb0ce1d089d0e78f

Comment: It's interesting to see the key being used to create the IV which probably isn't great for security but is actually a good way of keeping usage simple. It's the first time I've seen double-hashing and not been horrified :)

Comment: Basing the IV on the key does mean that encrypting multiple strings with the same key can leak some info (such as the number of identical cipher blocks at the beginning of the two strings). You may want to use `mcrypt_create_iv()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick pair of functions (actually, three of them) I just wrote that should meet your spec:

```
// Simple PHP encryption code by Ilmari Karonen, v1.0
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/30239440
// This code is released into the public domain; use it any way you want.

$enc_algo = 'rijndael-128';   // Rijndael-128/256 = AES-256
$key_len = 32; $iv_len = 16;  // key and IV lengths for AES-256
$enc_mode = 'ctr';  // CTR and OFB modes don't need padding

$hash_algo = 'sha256';  // for HMAC; must output at least $key_len bytes
$nonce_len = 16;  // length of random nonce; arbitrary, 16 bytes = 128 bits

function encrypt( $key, $plaintext, $metadata = "" ) {
    global $enc_algo, $enc_mode, $key_len, $iv_len, $hash_algo, $nonce_len;
    // derive two subkeys from the original key
    $mac_key = hash_hmac( $hash_algo, 'mac', $key, true );
    $enc_key = hash_hmac( $hash_algo, 'enc', $key, true );
    $enc_key = substr( $enc_key, 0, $key_len );

    // derive a "synthetic IV" from the nonce, plaintext and metadata
    $temp = $nonce = ( $nonce_len > 0 ? mcrypt_create_iv( $nonce_len ) : "" );
    $temp .= hash_hmac( $hash_algo, $plaintext, $mac_key, true );
    $temp .= hash_hmac( $hash_algo, $metadata, $mac_key, true );
    $mac = hash_hmac( $hash_algo, $temp, $mac_key, true );
    $siv = substr( $mac, 0, $iv_len );

    // encrypt the message
    $enc = mcrypt_encrypt( $enc_algo, $enc_key, $plaintext, $enc_mode, $siv );
    return base64_encode( $siv . $nonce . $enc );
}

function decrypt( $key, $ciphertext, $metadata = "" ) {
    global $enc_algo, $enc_mode, $key_len, $iv_len, $hash_algo, $nonce_len;
    // derive two subkeys from the original key
    $mac_key = hash_hmac( $hash_algo, 'mac', $key, true );
    $enc_key = hash_hmac( $hash_algo, 'enc', $key, true );
    $enc_key = substr( $enc_key, 0, $key_len );

    // unpack MAC, nonce and encrypted message from the ciphertext
    $enc = base64_decode( $ciphertext );
    $siv = substr( $enc, 0, $iv_len );
    $nonce = substr( $enc, $iv_len, $nonce_len );
    $enc = substr( $enc, $iv_len + $nonce_len );

    // decrypt message
    $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt( $enc_algo, $enc_key, $enc, $enc_mode, $siv );

    // verify MAC, return null if message is invalid
    $temp = $nonce;
    $temp .= hash_hmac( $hash_algo, $plaintext, $mac_key, true );
    $temp .= hash_hmac( $hash_algo, $metadata, $mac_key, true );
    $mac = hash_hmac( $hash_algo, $temp, $mac_key, true );
    if( $siv !== substr( $mac, 0, $iv_len ) ) return null;

    return $plaintext;
}

// extra function for password-based encryption
function password2key( $password, $count = 100000, $salt = "" ) {
    global $hash_algo;
    return hash_pbkdf2( $hash_algo, $password, $salt, $count, 0, true );
}
```

And here's a simple test case / usage example:

```
$key = password2key( 'password' );
echo "key (in hex): "; var_dump( bin2hex( $key ) );

$enc = encrypt( $key, 'a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' );
echo "encrypted: "; var_dump( $enc );

$dec = decrypt( $key, $enc );
echo "decrypted: "; var_dump( $dec );

# try to modify one bit of the encrypted message, see if decryption fails
$fake_enc = base64_decode( $enc );
$fake_enc = substr( $fake_enc, 0, -1 ) . ( substr( $fake_enc, -1 ) ^ "\001" );
$fake_enc = base64_encode( $fake_enc );
$dec = decrypt( $key, $fake_enc );
echo "tampered message: "; var_dump( $dec );

# decoding with wrong metadata should also fail
$dec = decrypt( $key, $enc, 'wrong' );
echo "wrong metadata: "; var_dump( $dec );
```

The code above implements a custom [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) mode based on the [AES-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) cipher in [CTR mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CTR_mode)<sup>1</sup>, combined with [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)-[SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-256) for message authentication.  It uses the [Mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.constants.php) and [Hash](http://php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php) modules, which I believe should both be fairly commonly available.

The interface is deliberately kept as simple as possible:

- `encrypt( $key, $message )` encrypts the message using the given key, and returns the resulting [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded ciphertext.
- `decrypt( $key, $ciphertext )` decrypts the output of `encrypt()` using the same key, and returns the plaintext message, or `null` if message validation fails (which could mean that the message has been tampered with, or that the key is incorrect).

Both functions can also take an optional `$metadata` parameter<sup>2</sup> for "associated data", such as sender / receiver IDs or other message headers.  In plain terms, if the metadata string passed to `decrypt()` doesn't match the one passed to `encrypt()`, the message is assumed to have been tampered with (e.g. by an attacker trying the modify the headers), and validation will fail.

The extra helper function `password2key()` at the bottom is just a thin wrapper around Mcrypt's implementation of [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).  If you "key" is not a random string with high entropy, you should call `password2key()` to derive the actual encryption key from it.  The `$count` parameter controls the slowness of the derivation process, and should be set as high as you reasonably can; the default value of 100,000 provides a little over 16 bits worth of [extra resistance against brute force attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching).

---

The specific method I've used to combine  components is loosely based on the [SIV](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/siv.pdf) construction by Rogaway and Shrimpton, but using HMAC instead of their CMAC* algorithm.  Note that this is *not* a classical [Encrypt-then-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#Encrypt-then-MAC_.28EtM.29) scheme, but rather an [Encrypt-and-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#Encrypt-and-MAC_.28E.26M.29) one; while E&M doesn't have the same kind of generic security proof as EtM, I believe this instantiation should still be secure, since HMAC used with a secure hash function is known to be privacy-preserving (i.e. it does not leak information about the plaintext).

The advantage of this SIV-like construction is that it reduces the reliance on the [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce), and thus on the system RNG; even if the nonce is not always unique, the "synthetic IV" almost certainly is (unless the plaintexts also happen to be identical).  Thus, even if *no* nonce is used (i.e. even if  `$nonce_len = 0`), this scheme still only leaks minimal information about the plaintexts (essentially, their length, and whether two plaintexts are identical).  A unique nonce eliminates the second leak, by ensuring that even identical plaintexts encrypt differently.

There are other ways in which the code above is designed for robustness in favor of efficiency.  For example, while it would *probably* be safe to just feed `$key` directly to both HMAC and AES, I explicitly derive separate quasi-independent subkeys from it.  One advantage of this, besides a bit of extra confidence that there are no unforeseen attacks based on key reuse, is that the input key can have an arbitrary format; it need not be a random 32-byte binary string, like a raw AES key needs to be.

---

<sup>1) The PHP Mcrypt interface [doesn't seem to have a constant for CTR mode](http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.constants.php), but the underlying Mcrypt library should support it.  If yours doesn't, for some reason, try setting `$enc_mode = 'nofb';` for OFB mode instead.</sup>

<sup>2) The code given above only takes one metadata string, but it would be straightforward to modify it to take several, if needed.</sup>

Answer (score -3):

For me, `md5()` is the best choice.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php